# JQuery display alert with multiple checkboxes selected after click a submit button

Tags: jquery

these code only give me one selected checkbox in a aletr message after a click submith button when I selected more than one value can somebody help me please thanks in advance

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
submitHandler: function() { 

contact = $('input[name=contactMethod]:checked').val();
alert(contact);

}
});


Email<input type="checkbox" value="email" name="contactMethod">
Home Phone<input type="checkbox" value="homephone" name="contactMethod">
Mobile<input type="checkbox" value="mobile" name="contactMethod">
Post<input type="checkbox" value="post" name="contactMethod">
```

Comment: Please tidy a bit your code and make sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `.map` function to get all the values:

```
contact = $('input[name=contactMethod]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

The reason being, if more than one is checked, it will just give you the first one. The `.map()` returns a nice array.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fuwfd/

Answer (score 1):

`val()` only gets the value of the first element in the collection, you have to iterate to get all of them :

```
var contact = $.map($('input[name=contactMethod]:checked'), function(el,i) {
                  return el.value;
              });

alert(contact.join(', ')); // note : contact is now an array of all the values
```